# Graphs - connected graph with edge disjunctive cycles

Tags: graph-theory

I have connected graph $G$, with nine vertices, such that the list of vertex-degrees is $\{x, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1\}$. I need to find $x$ for which $G$ will have no less than $3$ edge disjunctive cycles. How can I calculate it? And then sketch it. Thanks for yours advices, I´m totally confused about this problem.

EDIT:
I´m sorry I´m not from english talking countries threfore maybe I translate some terms badly. Coherent mean that exists path between every pair of vertices (the graph has only one connected component).

Comment: Can you please define "coherent"? And what does your list mean - is it the orders of the vertices?

Comment: Please define what a coherent graph is.

Comment: I edited the question. Hope you understand now.

Comment: The usual word for "coherent" is "connected", by the way, and the usual word for a vertex's "level" is its "degree".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first sum up what we know about your graph: It has at least two vertices of degree 1, but these vertices cannot be contained in any cycle. Your graph contains at least 3 cycles. Each cycle has at least 3 edges, therefore the total number of edges in your graph is at least $3\cdot 3+2=11$. ($+2$ stands for those edges which join the two vertices of degree 1 with the rest of the graph.) The sum of all degrees is equal to the twice of the number of edges. Hence: $x+4+3+4\cdot 2+2\cdot 1\geq 2\cdot 11=22$. So $x=5$ or $x=7$. (Note that $x$ can not be an even number, since the sum of degrees must be even.) For both possibilities I was able to draw easily a suitable graph.

[image]